# How can i fire the contents of a CSV file through a stored procedure (to get it into a database in the right format)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures, import

Ok, so the background to the story. I am largely self taught the bits of SQL i do know, and it tends to be just enough to make things work that need to work - albeit with a fair bit of research for the most basic jobs!

I am using a piece of software which grabs a string of data, and then passes it straight to an SQL stored procedure to move the data around, perform a few tasks on the string to make it the format i need it to be, and then grabs lumps of this data and places it in various SQL tables as outlined by the SP. I get maybe half a million lines of data each day, and this process works perfectly well and quickly. However, should data be lost, or not manage to make it through to the SQL database correctly, i do still have a log of the 500,000 lines of raw data in CSV file format.

I cant seem to find a way to simply bulk import this data into the various tables in the various formats it needs to be in. Assuming there is no way to re-pass this data through the 3rd party software (i have tried and failed), what is the best (read easiest for a relative lamen) way to send each line of this CSV file through my existing stored procedure, which can then process and import the data as normal? i have looked at the bcp utility, but that didnt seem to be viable (or i am not well enough informed to make it do what i need). I have also done the usual trawling of the web (and these forums) to see if anything jumped out at me as the obvious way forward, but come up a bit dry.

Apologies if i am asking something a bit 101, but i would certainly be grateful if anyone could help me out with this - if i missed out any salient bits of information, let me know! :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The [SQL Server Import/Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) is a point and click solution that can be used to import CSV files into SQL Server.

The wizard builds an SSIS package behind the scenes, which can be saved and scheduled to run as needed. The wizard doesn't give you much in the way of data transformation, but the data could be loaded into a staging table and then processed by your existing stored procedure.

Comment: This sounds interesting - I always like the sound of point and click! :). I have had a look at you link, and concluded it will take me a few hours maybe to understand what that tool is about, which i will start on hopefully this AFT, to see if it does what i need. You also mention a staging table - if i were to bulk insert into a table, would it then be possible to run all of that table through my SP? if this is more viable than running a CSV through the SP as i had hoped, i could look at this instead, as i am pretty compfortable with basic bulk inserts (with no data manipulation implicit).

Comment: @DarrenJ Yes, use the stored procedure to select from the staging table, modify data as needed, and insert into destination table(s).